# ng-disabled active/inactive

Tags: angularjs

http://jsfiddle.net/zjqz6wjL/

I have 3 buttons, when you click on a button they all become disabled.

It would be nice if only the button I click becomes disabled and the other two remain active. When clicking on another button that one becomes disabled and in turn reactivating the previously disabled button back to active state.

```
        <button ng-click="disableClick()" ng-disabled="isDisabled" ng-model="isDisabled">Disable ng-click 1</button>
```

Comment: Your three buttons have the same ng-model. That's a mistake.

Comment: In fact `ng-model` is unused here. Its `<button>`s, not `<input>`s

Comment: you can simply initialize value on ng-click and toggle which one to disable/enable. see my below answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31434307/angular-ng-disabled-active-inactive/31439455#31439455

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this :

```
angular.module('ngToggle', [])
    .controller('AppCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.btns = [
            {name:'1',isDisabled:false},
            {name:'2',isDisabled:false},
            {name:'3',isDisabled:false}
        ];
        $scope.disableClick = function(btn) {
            alert("Clicked!");
            angular.forEach($scope.btns,function(_btn){
                _btn.isDisabled = false;
            });
            btn.isDisabled = true;
            return false;
        }
}]);
```

With this template :

```
<body ng-app="ngToggle">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <button ng-repeat="btn in btns" ng-click="disableClick(btn)" ng-disabled="btn.isDisabled">Disable ng-click {{btn.name}}</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

See here  : https://jsfiddle.net/dy7g0snx/

- You don't need the `ng-model` directive here (it was unsed though).
- Use your btns as objects
- Get it as array
- Use `ng-repeat` directive to loop on it
- Pass the btn object in `disableClick` method
- Disable all buttons in the method
- Then enable the passed button

## EDIT

Inspired by the comment then the answer of Joaozito Polo, here an alternative if you don' want to use objects. It is not recommended in most case but with a use case with only 2 or 3 buttons, non-paramtric, it is acceptable.

In a such situation, you didn't need the `$scope.disableClick()` thus, no more need the controller too.

Just declare your angular module js-side :

```
angular.module('ngToggle', []);
```

And use `ng-click` then `ng-disable` directives in content corelations :

```
<body ng-app="ngToggle">
    <button ng-click="disabled = 1" ng-disabled="disabled == 1">Disable ng-click 1</button>
    <button ng-click="disabled = 2" ng-disabled="disabled == 2">Disable ng-click 2</button>
    <button ng-click="disabled = 3" ng-disabled="disabled == 3">Disable ng-click 3</button>
</body>
```

Note that I removed the `ng-controller` directive too, because it will not defined js side now.

See the [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/sukdmtxs/2/)

Comment: He can also to use a "lastClicked" field, to disable only last clicked button.

Comment: You can post your own solution alternative. But I think your idea is not very usefull because passing the `btn` object in parameter is a direct way to get the `lastClicked` button (the clicked one, actually). So you would just add no needed information. But maybe you mean something even different.

Answer (score 2):

You can choose to extract to independent `directives`. There are two directives: `buttonGroup` and `myButton`. In `buttonGroup`, the property `disabledBtnName` stores the name of the only disabled button. In `ng-repeat`, only the button with name `disabledBtnName` will be disabled. It is easy to be reused, say, in many different pages.

```
angular.module('ngToggle', [])
    .directive('buttonGroup', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        template:
            '<div>' +
            '<button ng-repeat="btn in buttons" ng-disabled="btn.name == disabledBtnName" ng-click="disableMe(btn)" ng-bind="btn.text"></button>' +
            '<div ng-transclude></div>' +
            '</div>',
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.buttons = [];
            this.addButton = function (btn) {
                $scope.buttons.push(btn);
            };
            $scope.disableMe = function (btn) {
                $scope.disabledBtnName = btn.name;
            };
        }]
    };
}])
    .directive('myButton', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            name: '@',
            text: '@'
        },
        require: '^buttonGroup',
        link: function (scope, iElement, attrs, btnGroupCtrl) {
            btnGroupCtrl.addButton(scope);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Simply use it like:

```
<body ng-app="ngToggle">
    <div button-group>
        <div my-button name="one" text="Button One"></div>
        <div my-button name="twp" text="Button Two"></div>
        <div my-button name="three" text="Button Three"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Check the online working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zjqz6wjL/4/

Answer (score 1):

You can store the last clicked button information, and check on ngDisabled:

```
<button ng-click="click(1)" ng-disabled="lastClicked == 1">Disable ng-click 1</button>
```

and your action:

```
$scope.click = function(btn) {
    alert("Clicked!");
    $scope.lastClicked = btn;
    return false;
}
```

You can see on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zjqz6wjL/6/)

Comment: Ok yes its interresting if the aim is to volontary not use object. In fact, choosing this option you can even wrote this : `<button ng-click="lastClicked = 1" ng-disabled="lastClicked == 1">Disable ng-click 1</button>`. I repeat: `ng-model` here is not required, and even, not used at all. With your approach, even the $scope.click() is not required... In fact, no need to any controller! Just declare the module. See here https://jsfiddle.net/sukdmtxs/2/

Comment: sorry, I just copied the original <button>... ng-model isn't required. I will to correct my post.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have managed to do without use of controllers :

```
<body ng-app="ngToggle">
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-init = "disabled=0">
    <button ng-click = "disabled = disabled == 1 ? 0 : 1"  ng-disabled="disabled == 1" ng-model="isDisabled">Disable ng-click 1</button>
   <button ng-click="disabled = disabled=== 2 ? 0 : 2" ng-disabled="disabled == 2" ng-model="isDisabled">Disable ng-click 2</button>
   <button ng-click="disabled = disabled=== 3 ? 0 : 3" ng-disabled="disabled == 3" ng-model="isDisabled">Disable ng-click 3</button>
</div>
```

here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zjqz6wjL/8/

Comment: `ng-model` is absolutely not needed/required/used here.